# writing ontModel as owl not as rdf by jena

Tags: jena, owl

I have a owl ontology, I read it into Jena `OntModel`. then I update it at runtime. Now I want to write it back as a **OWL** ontology. I am using the code below:

```
RDFWriter writer = model.getWriter("RDF/XML");
```

`writer.write(model, out, root_uri);`

... gives me **RDF** syntax and not the **OWL** syntax. How can I write the `OntModel` into **OWL** syntax?

Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Jena doesn't support the OWL/XML syntax. It only support various RDF syntaxes, including RDF/XML and Turtle. See [here](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) for Jena's supported formats.

So you either need to work with one of these syntaxes (which can express all of OWL just fine).

Or switch to a different library that supports OWL/XML, like the [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

Of course, if you are using `getWriter("RDF/XML")`, it will be written in RDF/XML, which is one serialisation format for RDF and all RDF formats are serialisation syntaxes for OWL.
There is very few cases when one needs to use a non-RDF syntax when writing OWL programmatically but if you want to do so, try using the [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/), which can write OWL in [OWL/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-xml-serialization/), in [OWL 2 Manchester syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/), or in [OWL 2 functional syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/).